# Update feeditem createddate once it has been inserted

Tags: apex, visualforce, feeditem, feedcomment

I have a feeditem record which his displayed in the UI of a popup in a customized salesforce page. I want to edit this date. But from what I read, it is not possilble to edit the createddate for feeditem once it has been inserted. What I want to know is that, is there any workaround where I can update the feeditem createddate.

Answer (score 1):

CreatedDate being a System Audit field, we cannot edit this field.

You can set this field while performing Data Import.

[Enable Create Audit Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Enable-Create-Audit-Fields&language=en_US)

Comment: This is not the case for Chatter, you need to use a different setting:
`Insert System Field Values for Chatter Feeds`